# Create a jQuery function that can be called in multiple events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which deletes row of a table.

Code goes like this:

```
jQuery(function() {
    initDeleteRow();
});

function initDeleteRow() {
    var containers = $('.management-section');
    $.each(containers, function() {
        if ( containers.length ) {
            var container = $(this);

            var deleteBtn = container.find('.activity-selected.delete');

            var individualDeleteBtn = container.find('.delete-row');

            deleteBtn.on('click', function(e) {

                var checkedBox = $(this).closest('.management-section').find('tbody .selection-check:checked');

                if ( checkedBox.length ) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        checkedBox.closest('tr').remove();
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            container.find('.activity-buttons').removeClass('selected-buttons').addClass('second-animation');

                            setTimeout(function() {
                                container.find('.activity-buttons').removeClass('second-animation');
                            }, 1040);

                        }, 100);

                    }, 1200);
                }

                    if($(this).closest('.management-section').find('tbody .selection-check:checked').length === $(this).closest('.management-section').find('tbody .selection-check').length) {

                            $(this).closest('.management-section').find('.check-all').prop("checked",false);

                    }
            });

        }
    });
}
```

However, I need to use some part of it in multiple occasions. For example,

```
deleteBtn.on('click', function(e) {
    // code inside this section needs to be used in another place
});

individualDeleteBtn.on('click', function(e) {
    // same code as above should run here with some small change such as it's not checkbox.
});
```

i tried putting everything inside a function like this:

```
deleteBtn.on('click', function(e) {
    deleteRowFunc();
});

function deleteRowFunc() {
    // all codes inside of deleteBtn.on('click', function(e) moved here
}
```

but it didn't work at all. not even any error in console. What am i missing here?

This is how the code looks after my change:

working Fiddle:     https://jsfiddle.net/4rwvaey9/2/
not working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4rwvaey9/1/

Comment: Kinda meaningless without the HTML it could be badly designed layout or just very complex and intricate layout (I noticed nested `setTimeout()` so it's probably the former). If you are looking for an agnostic answer cut back on the code dumping. If you're looking to resolve the issue so it works, include the HTML but try to isolate to the most relevant code. Read this section on [mcve]

Comment: @zer00ne Updated the post with working code

Comment: @zer00ne try checking 1 checkbox and click on "Delete Selected"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` refers to the current object, when you wrap it in your own function, it is no longer a jquery object.

What you need to do is simply add a parameter to your function and bind that to the event.

```
function deleteRowFunc(e)

deleteBtn.on('click', deleteRowFunc);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/puxztfL5/2/

Comment: this worked minor error in console. I have updated the question with working and not working fiddle if you'd see. try checking 1 checkbox and click on "Delete Selected"

Comment: @Lucian in your non working fiddle, you didn't do this change I specified.

Comment: I did that on my local copy and there was an error `container not defined`. i kept this non working fiddle to have the general idea of what i tried and what i should be changing it into.

Comment: cool, that helps. Thank you. could you edit your answer and add the link to fiddle there? i will and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the two jQuery objects with `add`, and then call `.on` on the combined collection:

```js
const a = $('#a');
const b = $('#b');
a.add(b).on('click', () => {
  console.log('clicked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">click a</div>
<div id="b">click b</div>
```

Or, for your code:

```
deleteBtn.add(individualDeleteBtn).on('click', function() {
  // ...
});
```